# Changing the starting index of a list (from 0 to 2)

Tags: python

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[]
```

how can i append a to b such that my starting index of b is 2.Rather than 0 being my starting index my index should start at 2

Comment: Use a slice. `b.append(a[2:])` (or maybe `extend` instead of `append`)

Comment: What is the result you expect? Every list always starts at 0.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to access the 1 using `a[2]` and the 2 using  `a[3]`, etc? The usual way to do that is to put a couple of dummy values at the start of the list, eg `a = [None, None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this

```
b = a[2:]
```

if you do the following,

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = []
b.append(a[2:])
print(b)
```

Your result will be `[[3,4,5]]`

the elements of a will be stored in a b as a list of lists. To just copy individual elements of a, use extend

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = []
b.extend(a[2:])
print(b)
```

This prints

```
[3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but if you want to put the elements of `a` to `b` starting from `a`'s 2nd position this will help:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = a[2:]
print(b)
```

Comment: i want to know if there is a way to start the index of b to 2

Comment: @hellriser That makes no sense.